# Best solution (api, sdk, etc.) to add chat/messaging to my Android/iOS app?

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, chat, messaging

I'm considering a custom implementation of messaging inside my app, but maybe there's a nice api/sdk/service that could be a better option.

I'd prefer something free to start with, maybe paid when my user database grows.

I have found for example: jiver.io, layer.com, quickblox.com.

I guess this question is more for other forums like Quora, but I'm trying. I hope I don't get too many downvotes. :)

Comment: https://github.com/ripienaar/free-for-dev#baas

Comment: Thanks pvllnspk, I already found layer and quickblox, and others. I asked the question to get opinions so I don't have to try them all. :)

Comment: give a try to https://www.applozic.com  PS: I am one of cofounder @Applozic

Comment: You may checkout ChatCamp - https://chatcamp.io. We offer chat SDK and messaging API for mobile and web apps. It's a cross platform solution built for iOS, Android and Web.

Answer (score 4):

Try using www.pubnub.com or Teamchat sdk (http://www.teamchat.com/en/time-to-upgrade-your-app-with-teamchat-sdk-2-1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try **Robbihanson** SDK for iOS. It is an XMPP Framework in Objective-C for the Mac / iOS development community.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).